# JasperReports JRXML JRBeanCollectionDataSource using variable/parameter as data

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to embed JRBeanJavaCollectionDataSource in jrxml. I want to display table. In jrxml I wrote:

```
<datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1">
<dataSourceExpression>
<![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($V{project})]]> `</dataSourceExpression>`
</datasetRun>
```

$V{project} must contain javaCollection. I don't know  how to write multiple line java code in variable expression in IReport 4.5 to get my javaCollection.It is possible? Or there is another way to get javaCollection